# Where should questions on Puppet configuration go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

When asking questions about how to configure XYZ on a given operating system using Puppet, should they be asked on stackoverflow or on unix.stackexchange when they relate to Linux?

As Puppet and Chef are largely provisioning tools, where would questions relating to them best be asked?

There are at least three or four sites that come to mind:

- stackoverflow.com - Questions relating to Puppet as it concerns software development.
- unix.stackexchange.com - Questions relating to Puppet as it concerns specifically Linux and Unix environments.
- serverfault.com - Questions relating to Puppet as it concerns administration of servers (ie: from a sysadmin perspective).
- superuser.com - Questions relating to Puppet as it concerns how to install and manage software X on system Y.

Where would the following question best be asked?

- puppet - Making sure a certain kernel version is installed and running?

If Puppet questions would be best asked on multiple sites, please advise and give examples as to which questions would belong where.

Comment: Does making sure a certain kernel version is installed and running have anything to do with puppet, other than being a software prerequisite?

Comment: I mean "How do I configure a host to have a certain kernel version and be running it with Puppet?" Certain software I'm using depends on kernel >= 3.8, which works out to `linux-image-generic-lts-saucy` on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As to that particular kernel question, it sounds like it really has nothing to do with Puppet.  The question could be asked as "How do I insure Kernel 3.8 and above," and it would still be the same question, without ever mentioning Puppet.  It certainly seems twice-removed from our usual questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: On another note, I'm not sure it's the community's responsibility to provide you with detailed examples, especially since someone will come along and decide that one of the examples is close enough to their question to make it on-topic, when in fact it isn't.  Rather, it's *your* responsibility to figure out, from reading the Help Center and lurking, whether or not a particular site will accept your question.

Comment: I think pretty much any question about Puppet would be on-topic on [unix.se] (assuming a question that's suitable for SE in the first place), but I don't know if it's necessarily the best site. We only have a handful of questions about Puppet on U&L.

Comment: So is it preferred that I just roll dice and hope my question doesn't get closed as being off-topic?

Comment: No, it's preferred that you study the scope of the sites, and figure out which site you question is best suited for.